# Is this isomorphism natural?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I constructed a linear map $\phi$ without choosing a basis, but in order to check that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, I chose a basis. Is $\phi$ still considered a natural isomorphism?

Edit: The problem is asking to construct a map for $V^{*}\otimes W \to Hom(V,W)$ where $V$ is finite dimensional, which I wrote down $\lambda \otimes w \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} \lambda(\bullet) w$. Now to show that this is an actual isomorphism, I had to select a dual basis for $V$.

I understand that you can do a change of basis and $\phi$ will still be both injective and surjective, but something about choosing a basis in the proof irks me when the problem specifies that the map to be natural.

Comment: The _fact_ of $\phi$ being an isomorphism doesn't depend on the _technique of proof_ of this fact. (Presumably, your _definition_ of $\phi$ is basis-independent.) Given what you've written, "yes, $\phi$ is a natural isomorphism".

Comment: I though every linear map is determined by its action on a basis, ergo regardless of one's choice, the basis "influence" is always there.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The problem is asking to construct an isomorphism for $V^{*}\otimes W \to Hom(V,W)$, which I wrote down $\lambda \otimes w \mapsto \lambda(\bullet) w$. Now to show that this is an actual isomorphism, I had to select a dual basis for $V$. I will put this in the original post.

Comment: This is a natural morphism of (bi)functors, which is an isomorphism when $V$ is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered in a comment:

> The *fact* of $\phi$ being an isomorphism doesn't depend on the *technique of proof* of this fact. (Presumably, your *definition* of $\phi$ is basis-independent.) Given what you've written, "yes, $\phi$ is a natural isomorphism". –  user86418 Jul 26 '13 at 15:35

You are allowed to use any tool you want for proving that the map is an isomorphism, for example bases (and you *have* to in this case, because finite dimensionality is equivalent to having a finite basis). Naturality is in the map, not in the proof.